# string clustering via similarity hashing/measure

Tags: hash, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I would like to summarize strings of medium size (10-20 characters) to groups.
That means, if two strings are very similar, e.g. "soccer" and "socer", the hash for both should be a similar. Similar in terms of an integer, or by a similarity measure returning 0 or 1 for "very similar".

Is there a benchmark or evaluation related to clustering methods?

Right now I am aware of

- Histogram and some [histogram intersection kernel](http://acberg.com/papers/mbm08cvpr.pdf).
- The [Levenstein Distance measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Or is this issue is solved for a very long time and there are only "standards"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The state of the art techniques to look into probably are MinHash, LSH, WTA hashes, etc.

What you are looking for is **not clustering, but near-duplicate detection**.

Such methods are reported to be used by Google News, for example, to detect near-duplicate news items (and there are plenty). Here, you should try the same approaches on characters and maybe n-grams.